# Create nuget with dependencies on beta

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

We are creating a nuget package for internal use where we normally have some dependencies on other nuget package. However now we need to create an package which relies on other nuget packages which is in beta for the moment.

I hope to do something similar to this:

```
     <group  targetFramework="MonoTouch">
        <dependency id="MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.PictureChooser" version="3.1.1" />
        <dependency id="MvvmCross.HotTuna.MvvmCrossLibraries" version="3.5.0-beta2"/>
      </group>
```

But I cant find any dokumentation if this should work at all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create the package with pre-release flag. It is not allowed to create release package with pre-release dependencies.

To do that you have to specify in your assembly:

```
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyInformationalVersion("1.0.0-beta")]
```

In the section **[Install Command Usage](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference#Install_Command)**.
The command `nuget install MvvmCross.HotTuna.MvvmCrossLibraries -Prerelease`.

> Prerelease flag "*allows prerelease packages to be installed*"

Comment: Is there any link to a Nuget documentation which would illustrate/document that step?

Comment: Please find nuget.exe command line documentation:   [http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference)

Comment: What specific part of that doc would be relevant to this answer?

Comment: In the section **Install Command Usage**. The command `nuget install MvvmCross.HotTuna.MvvmCrossLibraries -Prerelease`. Prerelease flag "_allows prerelease packages to be installed_".

Comment: Excellent: adding that information in the answer (with the direct link to the right section of the doc) is what makes an "ok" answer as a great answer. Doing that consistently answer after answer makes you a long-term valuable contributor to this Q&A site.